How can i see Grass token sent from bitget to my phantom wallet?
I bougth grass token in bitget and i sent them to the adress where my earnings of grass staking are sent but i cant see them in my wallet. How can i recover them or show them in my phantom wallet? I already ask to bitget and they answer that the withdraw was success so i have to ask to phantom. Did anybody happened the same?
